# Критическая ошибка Android 7.0

Tags: java, android

Сегодня получил отчет от Firebase Crash Reporting и это уже второй такой отчет. Перерыл кучу информации и ответа так и не смог найти.

```
android.view.Surface.nativeUnlockCanvasAndPost (Surface.java)
android.view.Surface.unlockSwCanvasAndPost (Surface.java:331)
android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost (Surface.java:312)
android.view.SurfaceView$4.unlockCanvasAndPost (SurfaceView.java:1031)
net.miniline.trackball.Classes.DrawThreads.Thread_SelectBlock.run 
(Thread_SelectBlock.java:266)
```

Вот сам run();

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    Canvas canvas;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        long curTime = getTime();
        long elapsedTime = curTime - prevRedrawTime;

        if (elapsedTime < REDRAW_TIME) { continue; }

        canvas = null;

        try
        {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder)
            {
                draw(canvas);
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {}
        finally
        {
            if (canvas != null)
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

        prevRedrawTime = curTime;
    }
}
```

На Api 10 (Android 2.3.3) работает отлично. На эмуляторе я не смог вызвать эту ошибку как не старался.

Comment: Это полный стектрейс?

Comment: Посмотрите исходник этого класса https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/nougat-mr1.1-release/core/java/android/view/Surface.java, может что-то поймете?

Comment: Да это полный стектрейс. Еще отчет о такой же ошибке пришел с андроид 6.0.1 телефон Xiaomi Redmi Note 3